# Is a teleconference wedding halachically valid?

Tags: marriage, technology, edim-witnesses

Suppose that a couple goes into a conference room and sets up a web cam. The *edei kiddushin* (witnesses) watch the declaration via Skype, etc.

(Offhand, I don't think a chuppa is an absolute requirement, but, if it is, assume they see that, too.)

Is the couple halachically validly married by this method? Or do the witnesses need to be physically there?